# remove text in between delimiters in a string - regex

Tags: c#

I have been trying real hard understanding regular expression, Is there any way I can replace character(s) that is between two regex/ For example I have

```
string datax = "a4726e1e-babb-4898-a5d5-e29d2bc40028;POPULATE DATA AØ99c1d133-15f5-4ef5-bc59-  d9ed673b70c6;POPULATE DATA BØ";
```

how to remove string between regex ";" and "Ø" ???

i try to use code like this :

```
string xresult = Regex.Replace(datax, @"(?<=;)(\w+?)(?=Ø)", "");
```

But not working.
please corrected and give me solutions...
thanks...

i want the result like this sir :

```
string datax = "a4726e1e-babb-4898-a5d5-e29d2bc40028;Ø99c1d133-15f5-4ef5-bc59-d9ed673b70c6;Ø";
```

Comment: Define "not working". Show expected and actual output.

Comment: And you need regex to cause you a headache and parse a very basic string because?

Comment: @JamesBarrass Feel free to provide a solution using basic string handling methods.

Comment: read again my question sir... please give me solution... :)

Comment: It looks like you are trying to extract GUIDS from text?  if so use ([a-z0-9]{8}[-][a-z0-9]{4}[-][a-z0-9]{4}[-][a-z0-9]{4}[-][a-z0-9]{12}) as your pattern.

Comment: @Rawling Do you think it helps in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to understand regex a little better and how the replace function works. with regex you're defining capture groups, and with the replace function you want to replace those groups.

> how to remove string between regex ";" and "Ø" ???

Step 1: First find ";",then capture all characters up to and including "Ø".

That's `(;.*?Ø)`

- ( New Capture Group
- ; Match ";"
- . Match Anything
- * Zero or more times
- ? Be Lazy
- Ø Match "Ø"
- ) End Capture

Step 2: Replace each group with ";Ø"

> public static string Replace(string input, string pattern, string
>   replacement)

So you need to put back the ";Ø" you removed from the original capture.

```
    static void Test2()
    {

        foreach (string item in SO2588078())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }

        string input = "a4726e1e-babb-4898-a5d5-e29d2bc40028;POPULATE DATA AØ99c1d133-15f5-4ef5-bc59-  d9ed673b70c6;POPULATE DATA BØ";
        string regex = "(;.*?Ø)";
        string output = Regex.Replace(input, regex, ";Ø");

        if (output == string.Join(";Ø", SO2588078()) + ";Ø")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("TRUE");
        }
    }
```

An alternative would be to parse the string without regex. It's a simple format and this gives you more control over the process so you can see what's happening, why it's gone wrong and why it gives the results it does. Since you can step through it.

```
    private static IEnumerable<string> SO2588078()
    {
        string datax = "a4726e1e-babb-4898-a5d5-e29d2bc40028;POPULATE DATA AØ99c1d133-15f5-4ef5-bc59-  d9ed673b70c6;POPULATE DATA BØ";
        string temp = datax;
        while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(temp))
        {
            int index1 = temp.IndexOf(';');
            if (index1 > -1)
            {
                string guid = temp.Remove(index1);
                yield return guid;
                int index2 = temp.IndexOf('Ø');
                if (index2 > -1)
                {
                    temp = temp.Substring(index2 + 1);
                }
                else
                {
                    temp = null;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                temp = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: String handling? Regex? Why not both? :D